# Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/scss/hrms.scss. How to solve this using laravel vite?

Tags: laravel, sass, vite

I'm using laravel 9 and vite for building scss and js files. After running the `npm run build` command in production I'm getting the above error. Please help me to solve.

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/scss/app.scss", "resources/js/app.js"],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the missing file resources/scss/hrms.scss in vite.config.js like below:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/scss/app.scss","resources/scss/hrms.scss", "resources/js/app.js"],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

You can now use this file in the blade as

```
@vite(['resources/scss/hrms.scss'])
```